# How to fill a pandas dataframe through a for loop?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Question is related to this function in particular

```
def jsontodataframe(): #collect OHLC data from scstrade

    companies = {'Habib Bank Limited':'HBL','Engro Chemical':'ENGRO'}
    url = 'http://www.scstrade.com/stockscreening/SS_CompanySnapShotHP.aspx/chart'

    payload = {"date1":"01/01/2019","date2":"06/01/2019","rows":20,"page":1,"sidx":"trading_Date",
    "sord":"desc"}

    for company in companies:
        payload["par"] = companies[company]
        #print(payload)
        json_data = requests.post(url, json=payload).json() #download the json POST request from scstrade
        json_normalize(json_data)
        df = pd.DataFrame(json_data) #convert the json to pandas dataframe
        df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(json_data['d'], errors='ignore')
        df.columns = ['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Change'] #rename the columns to better names

        df['Date'] = df['Date'].str.strip('/Date()')
        df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], origin='unix', unit='ms') #convert unix timestamp to pandas datetime and set the index
        df['ID'] = companies[company]
        df.set_index(['ID'], inplace=True)
        print(df.head())

    df.to_csv("OHLC_values.csv") #save .csv file for later usage
```

Currently the `df` variable keeps getting overwritten each time and my output is like this: [image: Picture of my output]

I thought about using append but that would be a massive performance hit and I want the code to be as efficient as possible (so that I can easily scale it later on). Right now the df.columns line is redundant so should I just define my dataframe outside of the for loop? But that json_normalize function will bring in column names of its own then so thats kinda necessary.

Ideally I just want one big dataframe and then later convert that to one .csv file

Comment: You can maintain a list of dataframes, and then concatenates these together at the end.

Comment: This might be a lame question but once Im working with data from say hundreds of companies would this be the best/fastest way of going about this problem? (By this I mean your solution which I followed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Ideally I just want one big dataframe and then later convert that to one .csv file

This could be achieved using [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

```py
import calendar, requests
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

def jsontodataframe():

    companies = {'Habib Bank Limited':'HBL','Engro Chemical':'ENGRO'}
    url = 'http://www.scstrade.com/stockscreening/SS_CompanySnapShotHP.aspx/chart'

    payload = {"date1":"01/01/2019","date2":"06/01/2019","rows":20,"page":1,"sidx":"trading_Date",
    "sord":"desc"}
    data = []
    for company in companies:
        payload["par"] = companies[company]

        json_data = requests.post(url, json=payload).json() 
        json_normalize(json_data)
        df = pd.DataFrame(json_data) 
        df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(json_data['d'], errors='ignore')
        df.columns = ['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Change'] 

        df['Date'] = df['Date'].str.strip('/Date()')
        df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], origin='unix', unit='ms') 

        df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.floor('d') # return only dates

        ### update
        df['Month_as_number'] = df['Date'].dt.month # created a column with a month as number - 5, 11 etc.
        df['Month_as_name'] = df['Month_as_number'].apply(lambda x: calendar.month_abbr[x]) # 5 as May etc
        ###

        df['ID'] = companies[company]
        df.set_index(['ID'], inplace=True)
        data.append(df)
    # save to csv instead of returning dataframe    
    pd.concat(data).to_csv('OHLC_values.csv', index=False)
```

---

So I edited my initial answer. Now the function saves dataframe to `.csv` file.
Also, I stripped `date` column to only dates.

Comment: Okay so that worked. Two things: What would be the best place to convert the dataframe to csv? Want it inside a function and not just lying some place around main, should I just modify your return pd.concat(data) line and finish the df operations and the to_csv all over there? And how do I fix the ugly date format? Not sure how to remove the time (since its useless), also I need to visualize the data now and how would I go about drawing separate plot lines based on the ID? Right now just the sheer amount of dates on a barcharts x-axis is unreadble for me, need to make it prettier/less cramped

Comment: @AjwadJaved, I edited my answer. Now the function saves concatenated dataframe to a csv file, and also time has been removed (now it's only daes)

Comment: Okay so last thing but what would be the most efficient way to take the month (which is now between the two hyphens) and just use that for our x-axis "months" value? We can use that then for our barcharts and stuff

Comment: @AjwadJaved, please see my answer. I added both options - to have a month column as a number and as its name

Comment: Im getting a ```AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values``` this way? Just added ```df['Month_as_number'] = df['Date'].dt.month``` line to my barchart function and then set ```plt.xlabel('Month_as_number')```

Comment: That means you have to first convert a column to a datetime format. Inside of a function a column is first converted to a datetime, then .dt accessor is called to strip month values. If you loaded a csv with scraped data, you would need to convert column once again to datetime and call .dt after that, outside of a function. @ajwadjaved